# Is there anything a dual bevel mitre saw can do that a table saw can not?

Tags: table-saw, miter-saw

I am setting up a workshop in a small space. Unfortunately it is not really large enough for every tool and machine I would like. In the near future I intend to do a lot of work with sheet materials so a table saw is quite high up on the list of things I'd like - but it would mean other tools might not be given a permanent installation.

My question is, can a table saw with a parallel fence, cross cut fence and mitre gauge do all of the jobs a dual bevel mitre saw can - even if it may not be able to do some of those jobs as quick?

Thanks

Comment: Come at this another way, what was it that led you to the thought that a mitre saw was actually one of the tools you needed? Forget want, focus on *need*. Realise that minimal space very much argues against a mitre saw. But for a lot of woodworkers it doesn't even come down to that, a mitre saw is just a non-essential full stop. Not only do some not have one, more than a few have ditched theirs when they realised that they could do everything it provided a different way..... particularly if they have a decent table saw and are dedicated to getting the most out of it. [contd]

Comment: *"Is there anything a dual bevel mitre saw can do that a table saw can not?"* I presume you mean a compound mitre saw here, and beyond certain limits the answer may be yes. But the majority (possibly the vast majority) of tasks fall within those 'certain limits' which is why so many woodworkers don't have one and don't feel the lack.

Comment: Easily (and safely) cut a 10-ft long 2x4 into (2) 5-ft pieces.
This might be useful to you:
https://www.familyhandyman.com/project/how-to-build-a-flip-top-workbench/

Comment: If you ever try trim (base, casing, crown) on a tablesaw, you’ll buy a miter saw.

Comment: TBH, I find a track saw is much more effective for cutting up sheet goods than the table saw. I've made a couple of simple ones out of leftover plywood that will work with the different size circular saws I've got. It's much easier to clamp that to a 4x8' sheet of plywood than it is to manhandle a full-size sheet across my table saw with accuracy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> can a table saw with a parallel fence, cross cut fence and mitre gauge do all of the jobs a dual bevel mitre saw can

They're different tools that do different jobs. A table saw can cut the same range of angles that aa miter saw can, including compound angles, but trying to cut the end of an 8' or 10' piece of moulding is very awkward on a table saw using just a miter gauge. It's easier if your table saw is equipped with a [sliding table](https://www.harveywoodworking.com/products/compass-st-1500-sliding-table), but still not as easy or as accurate as a miter saw in a station that provides plenty of support.

A second difference is that you can easily move a miter saw to where the work is, but table saws other than small "job site" saws are usually too big and heavy to take to the work.

If you're trying to decide between the two tools, or wondering whether you need both, think about the kind of work that you do. If you're cutting lots of long, narrow pieces, a miter saw would be a great tool. So if you plan to install a lot of moulding, lay a hardwood floor, or build a cedar strip canoe or kayak, you'll probably want a miter saw. A good policy is to buy a tool when you need it; for general woodworking, you might want to buy a table saw now, and buy a miter saw when the need arises.